# How to implement paginator in search results

Tags: python, django, pagination, paginator

I am able to get all my items from all categories displayed on search results, now I have to add paginator on my search result for all items in categories that have been searched for. How can I implement paginator on search results to display all items in categories paginated? With my code below, the search results do not paginate all item categories properly. I do not know if itertool will be a better idea.

```py
def search_result(request):
  query = request.GET.get('q')
  if query is None:
      return redirect("shop:homepage")
  else:
      item = Item.objects.all().order_by("timestamp")
      if item:
          item = item.filter(
                  Q(title__icontains=query)  
              ).distinct()

  if item.count() == 0:
      messages.error(request, "No search results found")

  paginator = Paginator(item, 1)
  page = request.GET.get('page')
  try:
      queryset = paginator.get_page(page)
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      queryset = paginator.get_page(1)
  except EmptyPage:
      queryset = paginator.get_page(paginator.num_pages)

  context = {
      'search': item,
      'pagination': queryset,
      'query': query,
  }
  return render(request, 'search_result.html', context)
```

```
    <nav class="my-4 flex-center" style="font-weight:400">
      {% if pagination.has_other_pages %}
      <ul class="pagination pagination-circle pg-blue mb-0">

      {% if pagination.has_previous %}
      <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ pagination.previous_page_number }}" aria-label="Previous">
      <span aria-hidden="true">Previous</span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}

      {% for i in pagination.paginator.page_range %}
      {% if pagination.number == i %}
      <li class="page-item active"><span class="page-link">{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
      {% else %}
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% if pagination.has_next %}
      <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="?page={{ pagination.next_page_number }}"aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">Next</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
      </li>
      {% endif %}

      </ul>
      {% endif %}
      </nav>
```

Comment: Here is answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490942/django-pagination-example-from-documentation-how-to-display-with-all-sites-nu

Comment: @naveen when the items in categories show up, then i click on int 2 in pagination, it takes me back to home page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to access pages from Paginator object "`Paginator.get_page`" and "`Paginator.page`". Where `get_page` method doesn't raise any exception if given page isn't a number but `Paginator.page` does.  You are using using "`get_page`" method but catching `PageNotAnInteger` exception, where this exception is raised by only  `Paginator.page` method.

From Django documentation

> Paginator.get_page(number) -> Returns a Page object with the
>   given 1-based index, while also handling out of range and invalid page
>   numbers.
>
> **If the page isn’t a number, it returns the first page**. If the page
>   number is negative or greater than the number of pages, it returns the
>   last page.
>
> Raises an **EmptyPage** exception only if you specify Paginator(...,
>   allow_empty_first_page=False) and the object_list is empty.
>
> Paginator.page(number) Returns a Page object with the given
>   1-based index. Raises InvalidPage if the given page number doesn’t
>   exist.

```
Possibility: Seems like page number you are getting via query string isn't a valid number
```

To make it explicit change get_page method with page method

```py
   page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        pagination= paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer, deliver first page.
        pagination = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range (e.g. 9999), deliver last page of results.
        pagination = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

     context = {
      'search': item,
      'pagination': pagination,
      'query': query,
     }
  return render(request, 'search_result.html', context)
```

Use logging on server or dev tools in browser to check if page number is going well in query string

Comment: @naveen...thank you. The problem now, when I search for an item, I get results for all items from different categories. How can I create a paginator for all items when I get results of my search.